# Как преобразовать строковый литерал в имя метода и выполнить его

Tags: python

У меня в объекте есть свойство self.operation и ему присвоено строковое значение, например 'ChangeConditionGoods'. Я знаю, что в одном из предков описан такой метод ChangeConditionGoods. Мне надо его выполнить. То есть написать нечто вроде self.ChangeConditionGoods(). То есть мне надо self.operation (строку) преобразовать в метод и выполнить. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте использовать метод `getattr`

```
getattr(self, "строка")()
```

Comment: Блин, я уже так делал и забыл. Спасибо!